# issue while publishing data source sql server using parameterized stored procedure with live connection to tableau server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, tableau-api

I have a parameterized stored procedure which takes a value from tableau parameter list, runs on the DB (sql server) and returns the data for views. It is a live connection. It works well on the desktop but when we publish it to the tableau server the view doesn't show . It keeps rendering and nothing shows us. Any suggestions on how to resolve it ?
I have a stored procedure as follow:

```
create procedure [] { @ID int } 
as 
begin 
   set nocount on;
   select col1, col2, col3 from Table1 where col3 = @ID
End
```

The ID is input as a parameter from Tableau Now when i use this in Tableau Desktop with a live connection to SQL server it works fine. However when i publish it to Tableau server the view keeps rendering continuously. Why does that happen ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have a stored procedure as follow:
 create procedure []
{
ID int
}
as
begin
set nocount on;
select col1, col2, col3 from Table1 where col3 = ID 
End

The ID is input as a parameter from Tableau
Now when i use this in Tableau Desktop with a live connection to SQL server it works fine. However when i publish it to Tableau server the view keeps rendering continuously. Why does that happen ?